# Using a scale in d3.js to fill up a vertical bar with 3 colors

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In D3, I want to fill up a vertical bar with 3 different colors. How can this be accomplished?

The bar has a "domain" of 0 to 3.

Red from 0 to 1.5.

Blue from 1.5 to 2.

Yellow from 2 to 3.

I can't figure out how to accomplish this. It seemed really simple, I would use 3 `<rect>`, each one would have a `Y` of the lower bound, and a `height` of the range distance.

This seemed to fail, since for the final bar, my scale returns a height of 0. Am I using scales wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/7V8vZ/

Comment: Maybe a [threshold scale](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3306362)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/7V8vZ/1/

Basically I couldn't do it with (min,max) data. I had to use a weird (min, height). This let me figure out where to position the rect, and then how tall to make it. Maybe d3 gives a scale meant for this?

I'm assuming there is a lot `d3.js` I'm not leveraging. So if you have a better way of doing it, please comment or answer!